# Did I Inverse Laplace correctly?

Tags: laplace-transform

$$L^{-1}\frac{4s}{(s-6)^{3}}$$
$$4L^{-1}\frac{s}{s^{3}}|s=s-6$$
$$4L^{-1}\frac{1}{s^{2}}|s=s-6$$
$$4L^{-1}\frac{1!}{s^{1+1}}|s=s-6$$
$$4te^{6t}$$

Is this correct? symbolab and Wolfram are giving me different answers...

Comment: Maybe you could add some words between your steps.  Your work is incomprehensible.

Comment: Are you replacing $s-6$ with $s$? If so, then you also need to replace $s$ with $s+6$. This is more easily understood if you use a different letter: if $u=s-6$ then $\frac{4s}{(s-6)^3} = \frac{4(u+6)}{u^3}=\frac{4}{u^2}+\frac{24}{u^3}$. So you get what you wrote and also another term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know residues, you can rewrite your function as
$$
\frac{4s}{(s-6)^3} = \frac{4(s-6)}{(s-6)^3} + \frac{24}{(s-6)^3} =
\frac{4}{(s-6)^2} + \frac{24}{(s-6)^3}
$$
and use the "translation rule" to invert the two terms separately.

Answer (score 0):

The ILT may be computed via the residue theorem as follows:

$$\frac{4}{2!} \frac{d^2}{ds^2} \left [s e^{s t} \right ]_{s=6}  = 2 \frac{d}{ds} \left [(1+s t) e^{s t} \right ]_{s=6} = 2 \left [(t (1+s t) + t) e^{s t} \right ]_{s=6} = (4 t+12 t^2) e^{6 t}$$

You seem to be missing the $t^2$ term.

Comment: Strange we were never shown the residue theorem...I've been to every single class

Comment: @Modrisco: No, I suspect you weren't.  This is typically not shown in an introductory course.  Still, it is a very useful way of computing ILTs.